# Intellij IDEA showing error on legit Scala code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, code-completion, lift

I am new to Scala and IntelliJ IDEA. I am learning Lift from [Simply Lift](http://simply.liftweb.net) examples. I have setup my IDE as per instructions provided [here](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Using_IntelliJ_IDEA_to_develop_Lift_applications). I am using Maven based approach.The Scala plugin is versioned (0.4.1084 -- latest as of June 30, 2011). IntelliJ IDEA version is 10.5.

The archetype is

```
 -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-blank_2.8.1 \
 -DarchetypeVersion=2.3 \
 -DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
 -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
 -DgroupId=com.company \
 -DartifactId=lift_test \
 -Dversion=1.0
```

When I started coding the [Snippet and Sitemap](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-3.1.html#Next) example. I see IDE show error (and nasty wavy line below the code) at the following line

```
  Menu.i("Info") / "info" submenus (
    Menu.i("About") / "about" >> Hidden >> LocGroup("bottom"),
    Menu.i("Contact") / "contact",
    Menu.i("Feedback") / "feedback" >> LocGroup("bottom")
    ),
```

The error says,

```
Expression of type (Menu.Menuable , Menu.Menuable with Menu.withSlash, 
Menu.Menuable) doesn't conform to expected type ConvertableToMenu
```

However, when I run a `Maven > Install` or `Compile 'Boot.scala` from IDEA they seem to run without error.

I am having hard time on getting Scala/Lift working perfectly on either of the two IDEs, IDEA and Eclipse.

Please let me know what am I missing?

---

I have added a bug report, you may see it here http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-3429?projectKey=SCL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin is still under development. Good code red and bad code green are both issues that arise in every day usage. If you want to help with the development of the plugin, please file a bug report with a short example demonstrating your issue.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/SCL